# jQuery query SVG for [style] attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I want to get all the SVG elements that have `style` attribute:

```
svgDocument = objectEl.getSVGDocument();
styled = $("[style]", svgDocument);
```

For unknown reason this returns **all** of the SVG elements inside image. I don't know why.

However, `svgDocument.querySelectorAll("[style]")` works.

Comment: Is this an HTML page with multiple SVG elements embedded? Are you trying to find all such elements within a single SVG document, or all throughout the page? Is this a single SVG document with jQuery? If you could provide a simple test case and the results you wanted, it would help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, @Phrogz has the point, but, anyway, try `$(svgDocument).find('[style]');`